# Rerender Component upon state change in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an app which calls two functions; MyCart and MyItems. I am trying to make it so when the button rendered in MyItems is called it calls a method inside the main app component (the parent) and changes the state but for some reason, it doesn't change the value in the MyCart span.

My code below is what I am trying to do but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

```
class ShopRemake extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            total: 0
        }

        this.changeTotal = this.changeTotal.bind(this);
    }

    changeTotal() {
        this.setState(prevState => {total: ++prevState.total});
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <MyItem changeTotal={this.changeTotal}/>
                <MyCart total={this.state.total}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

function MyItem(props) {
    return (
        <button onClick={props.changeTotal}> Click Me </button>
    );
}

function MyCart(props) {
    return (
        <span> Total Items: {props.total} </span>
    );
}
```

I want it so that after I click the button the span inside the MyCart to update accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must wrap the returning object literal into parentheses in your arrow functions. Otherwise curly braces will be considered to denote the function’s body. The following works:

```
p => ({ foo: 'bar' })
```

So the call to `setState` in `changeTotal` :

```
changeTotal() {
    this.setState(prevState => {total: ++prevState.total});
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

Should be replaced by the following :

```
changeTotal() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({total: ++prevState.total}));
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

Also, `setState` is asynchronous, you will need to either await it(not recommended) or use the callback as the second parameter to see the resulting state :

```
changeTotal() {
    this.setState(
        prevState => ({total: ++prevState.total}),
        () => { console.log(this.state) }
    );
}
```

---

EDIT :

Sidenote, the 2 components below in your code can be reduced into arrow functions for the exact same result, while making them easier to read :

```
const MyItem = ({ changeTotal }) => <button onClick={changeTotal}> Click Me </button>

const MyCart = ({ total }) => <span> Total Items: {total} </span>
```

And you can also convert `changeTotal` to an arrow function to avoid having to bind it in your constructor

Comment: Yo thank you dude, I have no idea how this works but it did :D

Comment: That's because JS will consider brackets : `{}` after a function declaration as instruction blocks and not a JSON object.
With parenthesis, you are telling your browser that this is an object. Glad I could help

Comment: @Treycos i guess there is a confusion on your Edit. MyItem and MyCart are already stateless functions on the original code. You are not making them stateless, you just convert them to arrow functions. This has no performance benefit, but easier on eyes.

Comment: @HarunAkgün Whoops, you're right, I thought I saw a class somewhere before changing them. So basically yes, changing them from classic to arrow functions only made them easier to the eye.

Comment: Yup no worries this was just an example in my code I changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your setState is not returning an object here.
Try to change your method changeTotal to this

```
changeTotal() {
     this.setState(prevState => ({ total: prevState.total + 1 }), () => 
     console.log(this.state));
}
```

The setState methods is asynchronous, if you want to log it's value, do this with a callback.

Comment: yep, figured it out now. Anyways thank you but unfortunately, you were second to answer so I can't tick it :/